# main thread waits for std::async to complete

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, stdasync

I am using `std::async` to create a thread, I want this new thread should execute separately and main thread should not wait for it. But here when I call std::async, a new thread is created but main thread is waiting for completion of `fun()`. I want main thread to execute parallely without waiting for `fun()` to complete. How should I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <future>
using namespace std;



void printid()
{
   cout << "Thread id is:" << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}

void fun(void *obj)
{

   cout<<"Entry"<<endl;
   printid();
   Sleep(10000);
   cout<<"Exit"<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    printid();
    std::async(std::launch::async, fun, nullptr);
    cout << "After call" << endl;
}
```

I am getting output:

```
Hello
Thread id is:22832
Entry
Thread id is:13156
Exit
After call
```

Answer (score 10):

A `std::future` object returned by `std::async` and launched with `std::launch::async` policy, blocks on destruction until the task that was launched has completed.

Since you do not store the returned `std::future` in a variable, it is destroyed at the end of the statement with `std::async` and as such, `main` cannot continue until the task is done.

If you store the `std::future` object, its lifetime will be extended to the end of `main` and you get the behavior you want.

```
int main()
{
    ...
    auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, fun, nullptr);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::async(std::launch::async, fun, nullptr);
```

Doesn't do anything with the returned `std::future`, leaving it to be destroyed. That's a problem because [`std::future`'s destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future) may block and wait for the thread to finish.

The solution is to hold on to the `std::future` for a while and let it be destroyed after you're done with everything else.

```
auto locallyScopedVariable = std::async(std::launch::async, fun, nullptr);
```

`locallyScopedVariable` will go out of scope at the end of `main` and then block until it completes.

Note that this still might not do quite what you want. The main thread could immediately yield the processor to the new thread and allow the new thread to run to completion before control is returned. The code can be corrected and still result in the output of the incorrect version.

Answer (score 0):

(1) In multi-threading program testing, protect shared resource (cout in this case) from being invoked from different threads at same time using a mutex.
(2) Check if future is ready in the main, you can do a timeout also.

```
void print_id() 
{
    lock_guard<mutex> locker(mutex_);
    cout << "Thread id is:" << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}

void print( string str) 
{
    lock_guard<mutex> locker(mutex_);
    cout << str << '\n';
}   

bool fun(void *obj)
{
   print("Entry");
   printid();
   Sleep(10000);
   print("Exit");
   return true;
}


int main()
{
    print("Hello");
    printid();
    std::future<bool> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, fun,nullptr);
    while(!fut->_Is_ready() )
    {
     }
    cout << "After call" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `while(!fut->_Is_ready() )` forces behaviour that is the same as what the asker does not want. The main thread is essentially blocked awaiting completion of the thread.