# scope block when use std::async in function other than the main function

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdasync

I have some problem with st::async when is use this in other function other than Main function, 
suppose, I have functions like flowing :

```
void printData() 
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Test Function" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void runningAsync()
{
    auto r = std::async(std::launch::async, test);
}

int main()
{
    runningAsync();

    std::cout << "Main Function" << std::endl;
}
```

the output of this code is :

```
Test Function
Test Function
Test Function
Test Function
Test Function
Main Function
```

that is not good, Main thread wait for other thread that be end.

I want runningAsync() function run in other thread and at the same time "Main Function" in main thread print on screan, this is possible with std::thread.

is that way for this running this functions an same time (concurrency)?

Comment: Source won't compile as it is. Change either test with printData or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This QUESTION answered in :

[main thread waits for std::async to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575385/main-thread-waits-for-stdasync-to-complete)

[Can I use std::async without waiting for the future limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531096/can-i-use-stdasync-without-waiting-for-the-future-limitation)

Whoever, If you store the std::future object, its lifetime will be extended to the end of main and you get the behavior you want.

```
void printData() 
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Test Function" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

std::future<void> runningAsync()
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async, test);
}

int main()
{
    auto a = runningAsync();

    std::cout << "Main Function" << std::endl;
}
```

That's a problem because  [std::future's destructor](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3451.pdf) may block and wait for the thread to finish. see this link for more details

Comment: Source won't compile as it is. Change either `test` with `printData` or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `std::async` returns a `std::future` which you store in an `auto` variable. As soon as your future runs out of scope (at the end of `runningAsync()`!), its destructor blocks until the task is finished. If you do not want that, you could for example store the future in a global container.