# std::future.wait_for blocking forever

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, ssl, future

I am crating SSL socket and when I try to connect to that socket my program hangs.

I found some issue that server does not send any data so SSL connection is waiting for the any response.

I decided to create future and kill it after timeout. But it is still hanging.

If you see to the code, below part is not executed: `cout<<"TEST";`

```cpp
{

     std::future<void> future = std::async(std::launch::async, 
     [&](){ 
              err = SSL_connect (m_ssl); 
          });

     std::future_status status;
     status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(t_timeout));
}

cout<<"TEST";
```

To simulate stopping response from server I just run:

```
for item in $(seq 1 1000); do sudo nc -i 100000ms -l 443 >> log.out; done;
```

How do I kill the SSL connection? 
I want to continue execution of code after kill the future.

**EDIT:**
I do not want to open another question for that. 
**Answer**: So i am sure now that this is because of future destructor. It is waiting for finish of code from the future body.

**Question 2:** 
How Can I fix above issue? I want to execute code after scope which future is in.

Is it OK to create thread and wait until timeout or ssl some mutex is unlocked?

Comment: Have you actually checked the value of `t_timeout`?

Comment: Yes its 3 seconds and future is exiting when I do debug with gdb its exiting from scope and it stopping execution(hangs) before `cout<<"TEST";`

Comment: If `SSL_connect` blocks indefinitely and does not return then neither threads or async code will help to get around it. There is no such thing as "killing" future.

Comment: @VTT What can help me? Manual create and kill the thread?

Comment: "Forever blocking" functions are broken by design, there is no way around it. At most you will be left with leaking blocked threads. Switching to some proper library / API could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when the future goes out of scope, its destructor might block as reported in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) for `std::future<T>::~future`:

It says explicitly:

> ... will not block for the shared state to become ready, except that it may block if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state.

In your case:

1. the shared state is not yet ready: SSL hangs forever
2. that  is the only (and so last) reference to the shared state.

---

The solution to your problem is that you have to make the scope of variable `std::future<void> future` such that it outlives the part of the code you want not to be blocked.

Check these answers:

- [main thread waits for std::async to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575385/main-thread-waits-for-stdasync-to-complete)
- [Can I use std::async without waiting for the future limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531096/can-i-use-stdasync-without-waiting-for-the-future-limitation)

[LIVE DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jdfJDDuh9Bd417v6)

Comment: So if he wants to see the `cout<<"TEST"` heshould not enclose the future in a block because at the end of the block its destructor is called.

Comment: What if the code is inside a function and he wants to print test in int main()?

Comment: @Rostin that is another question =)

Comment: I updated question and posted another one. Thank you Could We continue discussion here?

Comment: @DanielHornik check again my answer. I have updated it. Weather the destructor should block or not has been a point of discussion in the C++ for a while already =)

Comment: @DavideSpataro. Great :D Thank you so much I will make it as a class property and I am to solve the issue.